# -notmatch with ... (3 dots)

Tags: powershell

I have a strange problem with my PowerShell CSV tool. I have tried to write a small check that filters out certain names and characters. These names/characters are in a textfile like this:

```
XXX
nana
YYY
...
DDD
```

I do the check lie this:

```
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($fc_file.Text)
try {
    for() {
        $line = $reader.ReadLine()
        if ($line -eq $null) { break }
        # process the line
        Import-Csv $tempfile -Delimiter $delimeter -Encoding $char |
            where {$_.$fc_suchfeld -notmatch $line} |
            Export-Csv $tempstorage -Delimiter $delimeter -Encoding $char -NoTypeInfo
```

It works great until the line with the 3 dots. At this point almost all lines are deleted. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `.` is a wildcard that matches any one character, so `something -notmatch '...'` is almost always false. If you just want to match things literally, consider `-notlike` instead (but then don't use `*` and `?`, which are wildcards for `-like`). If you want to be *really* literal, use `-not $_.$fc_suchfeld.Contains($line)` (assuming `$_.$f_suchfeld` is a string).

Answer (score 5):

The `-match` operator does regular expression matches. `.` is a metacharacter in regular expressions, matching any character except newlines. Thus a regular expression `...` matches any line with at least 3 characters. If you want to use the lines from `$fc_file` as literal string matches you need to escape them:

```
... | where {$_.$fc_suchfeld -notmatch [regex]::Escape($line)} | ...
```

or do a wildcard match:

```
... | where {$_.$fc_suchfeld -notlike "*$line*"} | ...
```